# Assign a string to a button. Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have four buttons that are created identically programmatically in a for loop:

```
  let moreButton = UIButton(type: .system)
  moreButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 25)
  moreButton.center.x = self.view.center.x + 115
  moreButton.center.y = OficerAgendas.center.y + CGFloat(yOffset + 30)
  moreButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
  moreButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
  moreButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
  moreButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.76, green:0.49, blue:0.49, alpha:1.0)
  moreButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
  moreButton.setTitle("My Opinion", for: UIControl.State.normal)
  moreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(mainPage.buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
  self.view.addSubview(moreButton)
```

I have the basic code for a touch up inside click.

```
@objc func buttonAction(_ sender:UIButton!)
{
    print("Button tapped")
}
```

What I want the code to have the ability to do is distinguish what button is being pressed (since they are all "moreButton" identically I cant create separate buttonAction code).  Ideally, I could just assign what iteration of the for loop the button was created in (its a for item in 1...items type loop).  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a tag to the buttons:

```
moreButton.tag = 1
```

(or a variable if you use an iteration)

And then in the method you can get the button with a

```
switch sender.tag
{
    case 1: print("1")     // button 1 clicked
        break
    case 2: print("2")     // button 2 clicked
        break
    default: print("...")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just found out about the .tag property too, it works perfectly!